# Вывод данных из БД php PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Ребят, всем привет. Есть такая БД:

- Таблица products: id, title, link (для того, чтобы можно по ссылке открывать тот или иной товар, не только по ID);
- Таблица prod_prop: id, product_id, property_id, value;

  - Связь М:М, обеспечивает множественные свойства для товаров
- Таблица properties: id, title

Следующая функция возвращает данные, которые берутся из этих таблиц:

```
public static function getProductByName($link) {
        $db = Db::getConnection();
        $sql = 'SELECT p.*, 
                cat.name AS category_name, 
                cat.link AS category_link, 
                prop.title AS property_title,
                pr_prop.value AS property_value
                FROM products AS p
                JOIN category AS cat ON cat.id = p.category_id
                JOIN product_prop AS pr_prop ON pr_prop.product_id = p.id
                JOIN properties AS prop ON prop.id = pr_prop.property_id
                WHERE p.link = :link';        
        $result = $db->prepare($sql);
        $result->bindParam(':link', $link, PDO::PARAM_INT);        
        $result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $result->execute();        
        return $result->fetch();
    }
```

Проблема - данная функция возвращает лишь первые строки из таблиц prod_prop и properties, т.е. если в таблице prod_prop указано 3 свойства для 1 товара, он возвращает лишь одно.

> Вопрос: как сделать, чтобы свойства из данных таблиц возвращались в виде ассоциативного массива (т.е. чтобы попарно шло, пример массива, который хотелось бы видеть, будет ниже)? Нужно для вывода на страничке товара через цикл foreach.

Заранее спасибо!

Пример массива:

```
array(
    array(
        'title' => 'Длина',
        'value' => '40',
    ),
    array(
        'title' => 'Страна',
        'value' => 'Эквадор',
    ),
    array(
        'title' => 'Цена',
        'value' => '100',
    )
);
```

UPD сделал следующее:

```
$product = Product::getProductByName($link);
var_dump($product);
```

Ничего дельного не вышло, в БД 3 записи по этому ID, выводится лишь одна, вот дамп:

```
array(16) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "6"
  ["link"]=>
  string(10) "sweetbox-5"
  ["title"]=>
  string(44) "Коробка со сладостями #5 "
  ["description"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["meta_keywords"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["meta_description"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["price"]=>
  string(4) "5799"
  ["is_discount"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["discount_price"]=>
  NULL
  ["category_id"]=>
  string(1) "3"
  ["is_recommended"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["params"]=>
  NULL
  ["category_name"]=>
  string(40) "Коробки со сладостями"
  ["category_link"]=>
  string(8) "sweetbox"
  ["property_title"]=>
  string(29) "Количество букв"
  ["property_value"]=>
  string(1) "5"
}
```

UPD2: Поменял на fetchAll. Получается следующее:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(15) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "6"
    ["link"]=>
    string(10) "sweetbox-5"
    ["title"]=>
    string(44) "Коробка со сладостями #5 "
    ["description"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["meta_keywords"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["meta_description"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["price"]=>
    string(4) "5799"
    ["is_discount"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["discount_price"]=>
    NULL
    ["category_id"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["is_recommended"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["category_name"]=>
    string(40) "Коробки со сладостями"
    ["category_link"]=>
    string(8) "sweetbox"
    ["property_title"]=>
    string(29) "Количество букв"
    ["property_value"]=>
    string(1) "5"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(15) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "6"
    ["link"]=>
    string(10) "sweetbox-5"
    ["title"]=>
    string(44) "Коробка со сладостями #5 "
    ["description"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["meta_keywords"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["meta_description"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["price"]=>
    string(4) "5799"
    ["is_discount"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["discount_price"]=>
    NULL
    ["category_id"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["is_recommended"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["category_name"]=>
    string(40) "Коробки со сладостями"
    ["category_link"]=>
    string(8) "sweetbox"
    ["property_title"]=>
    string(33) "Количество цветов"
    ["property_value"]=>
    string(2) "23"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(15) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "6"
    ["link"]=>
    string(10) "sweetbox-5"
    ["title"]=>
    string(44) "Коробка со сладостями #5 "
    ["description"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["meta_keywords"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["meta_description"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["price"]=>
    string(4) "5799"
    ["is_discount"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["discount_price"]=>
    NULL
    ["category_id"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["is_recommended"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["category_name"]=>
    string(40) "Коробки со сладостями"
    ["category_link"]=>
    string(8) "sweetbox"
    ["property_title"]=>
    string(10) "Длина"
    ["property_value"]=>
    string(3) "100"
  }
}
```

UPD3: Цикл while:

```
$i = 0;
        while ($row = $result->fetchAll()) {
            $productList['product']['id']                       = $row[$i]['id'];
            $productList['product']['link']                     = $row[$i]['link'];
            $productList['product']['title']                    = $row[$i]['title'];
            $productList['product']['description']              = $row[$i]['description'];
            $productList['product']['meta_keywords']            = $row[$i]['meta_keywords'];
            $productList['product']['meta_description']         = $row[$i]['meta_description'];
            $productList['product']['price']                    = $row[$i]['price'];
            $productList['product']['is_discount']              = $row[$i]['is_discount'];
            $productList['product']['discount_price']           = $row[$i]['discount_price'];
            $productList['product']['category_id']              = $row[$i]['category_id'];
            $productList['product']['is_recommended']           = $row[$i]['is_recommended'];
            $productList['properties'][] = ['title' => $row[$i]['property_title'], 'value' => $row[$i]['property_value']];
            $i++;
        }
```

Результат цикла:

```
array(2) {
  ["product"]=>
  array(11) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "6"
    ["link"]=>
    string(10) "sweetbox-5"
    ["title"]=>
    string(44) "Коробка со сладостями #5 "
    ["description"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["meta_keywords"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["meta_description"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["price"]=>
    string(4) "5799"
    ["is_discount"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["discount_price"]=>
    NULL
    ["category_id"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["is_recommended"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  ["properties"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["title"]=>
      string(29) "Количество букв"
      ["value"]=>
      string(1) "5"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `данная функция возвращает лишь первые строки из таблиц prod_prop и properties, т.е. если в таблице prod_prop указано 3 свойства для 1 товара, он возвращает лишь одно.` Не верю. Запрос даёт всё. А вот в то, что Вы не сумели посмотреть остальные - в это верю.

Comment: @Akina добавил в вопрос результат дампа этой функции

Comment: не хотите `fetch` на `fetchAll` то заменить?

Comment: @teran упс. Спасибо! Только вот теперь другая проблема - с fetchAll он же делает 3 массива (добавил в вопрос). Каким образом можно сделать, чтобы был в массиве был массив с данными, а второй массив чтобы был уже со значениями? Т.е. Array( array( *тут все данные* ), array( *тут все значения свойств товара* ) );

Comment: циклом пройтись по результату и привести его к нужному виду.

Comment: @teran не совсем понимаю, как он должен выглядеть :( если есть подобное, то он это значение никуда не записывает, а если подобного нет, то он создает еще один массив со свойствами?

Comment: сначала возьмите первую строку за базовую `$item = $product[0]`, скопируйте ее. Пройдитесь по массиву  и извлеките пары `property_title` и `property_value`, на каждой итерации добавляйте их в `$item['properties'][] = [ 'title' => ..., 'value' => ..]`. в конце можете удалить исходные `unset($item['property_title'])`

Comment: @teran сделал так, как Вы сказали, добавил в конец вопроса. Почему-то цикл проходит 1 раз, затем ничего не происходит :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вот получили вы `$product` с помощью `fetchAll`. В результате имеете 3 строки, в каждой строки первые несколько значений одинаковы, два последних - ваши свойства - разные.
Упрощенно представим это так:

```
$product = [
    [ 'id' => 1, 'title' => 'товар', 'property_title' => 'длина',  'property_value' => 100], 
    [ 'id' => 1, 'title' => 'товар', 'property_title' => 'высота', 'property_value' => 200], 
    [ 'id' => 1, 'title' => 'товар', 'property_title' => 'ширина', 'property_value' => 300], 
];
```

А вы хотите получить массив вида

```
$product = [
    'id' => 1,
    'title' => 'товар',
    'properties' => [
         ['title' => 'Длина',  'value' => 100],
         ['title' => 'высота', 'value' => 200],
         ['title' => 'ширина', 'value' => 300],
    ],
];
```

Для этого все повторяющиеся данные возьмите из первой строки. Дальше циклом выберите значения свойств.

```
$item = $product[0];
foreach($product as $p){
    $item['properties'][] = [
           'title' => $p['property_title', 
           'value' => $p['property_value']
        ];
}
```

при желании удалите исходные `property_title` и `value` из `$item`:

```
unset($item['property_title']);
unset($item['property_value']);
```

в результате получите приведенный выше массив `$item` со вложенными массивом свойств.
Вместо такого цикла можно и другие варианты привести, например, `array_map`. А также задачу можно решить с помощью двух запросов вместо одного. Первый извлечет нужную информацию о товаре (1 строка), а второй 3 строки его свойств. С одной стороны лишний запрос, с другой нет дополнительного джойна и передачи большего объема данных, который впрочем тут не критичен.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Все получилось!

Answer (score 0):

Добрый день!

Иcпользуйте fetch, результаты запроса обрабатывайте циклом while (не foreach). Т.е. вместо:

```
return $result->fetch();
```

Используйте:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_LAZY))
{
   echo $row->name; //Ну или что вы там с этим хотели делать?
}
```

Comment: Странно, сделал while - не работает корректно. Приложил в конец вопроса цикл, который написал и результат этого цикла.

Comment: уберите из вашего скрипта $i, чтобы осталось вот так:
`$productList['product']['id']                      = $row['id'];`
только не понятен смысл этого кода, переменная же будет всё время перезаписываться, вам $i тогда как раз в $productList нужно ставить.